# Get file syntax selection in sublime text 3 plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have a very small plugin to open a perl file module starting from the use statement. It's really basic and it just replaces '::' with '/' and then if the file exists in one of the paths specified in PERL5LIB, it opens it.
I want it to run only when the open file syntax is selected as perl.
Is there any API to get that information?
This is the code that I have now:

```
class OpenPerlModule(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit=None, url=None):
        perl_file = url.replace("::", "/")
        perl_dirs = os.environ.get('PERL5LIB')
        for perl_dir in perl_dirs.split(':'):
            if (os.path.exists(perl_dir + '/' + perl_file + '.pm')):
                self.view.window().open_file(perl_dir + '/' + perl_file + '.pm')
                return
```

(The OS is Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code snippet you're looking for

```
self.view.settings().get("syntax")
```

You should check whether it's a syntax related to Perl or not. I suggest something like this:

```
syntax = self.view.settings().get("syntax")
syntax.endswith("Perl.tmLanguage") or syntax.endswith("Perl.sublime-syntax")
```

The second or clause is to cover the new syntax that's introduced in >=3080

Comment: `if "Perl" in syntax:` would be a much easier test, and would cover cases where the user has a 3rd-party Perl syntax like [`ModernPerl`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ModernPerl) installed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark this as the answer :-) I have looked around for some reference guides, but most of them are lacking one way or the other, maybe you also have a suggestion about where to find this kind of information?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `self.view.settings().get("syntax")` as described in Allen Bargi's answer, you could also get the scope for the current cursor position and check for `source.perl` in it:

```
import sublime_plugin

class FindScopeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # `sel()` returns a list of Regions that are selected. 
        # Grab the beginning point of the first Region in the list.
        first_point = self.view.sel()[0].a
        # now, get the full scope name for that point
        scope = self.view.scope_name(first_point)
        if "source.perl" in scope:
            print("You're using Perl. Yay!")
        else:
            print("Why don't you love Perl?")
```

Comment: This is also a valid solution but be careful that you might have nested syntaxes. It all comes down to your use case. for example you might have nested perl code inside a markdown document (MarkdownEditing plugin and my old Knockdown plugin both add the source.perl scope to highlight the nested code).